# What is the best way to write a baritone vocal and piano part?

Tags: notation

I am trying to figure out the most sensible way to write my music on a score as I compose and write music. I have little experience with scoring other than learning from sheet music of songs I like to play so sorry if this is a bit of an odd suggestion but I did an arrangement for my baritone voice with the chords in the treble clef and the vocal line in the bass clef. Is this a sensible way to write this arrangement or can someone please correct me and tell me where I am wrong or suggest a better way?

[image]

Comment: This is very similar to your last question so you'll get a very similar answer. If you are happy doing it this way, then do it. If other people have to read you music you should follow the conventions as @Jomiddnz's answer explains.

Comment: THank you. I think I am going to try find a hybrid approach where I can do both options simultaenously so in case I need to pass it on I can have the user friendly version :)

Answer (score 9):

Normally, for clarity, you would write the vocal line on a separate stave, and then under it the piano part.  If I understood your question correctly, this would work better, and would allow you to include the words if required.

Comment: THanks for your reply. I definitely am open to doing things this way but I am just wondering if there is any benifit of keeping things on the same grand staff. For looking at the intervals between the notes and compsing, isn't it helpful having the notes together like this so you can see more clearly the relationship between the vocal and piano parts?

Comment: If you notate the baritone voice in a separate channel you switch between the 2 views ( armani/Jomiddnz)

Comment: @Albrecht Do you mean in my DAW?

Comment: You will get better at opening up your vision and seeing more of the score at once as you read through.  It looks less cluttered with different lines set separately.

Comment: @armani No, there is no benefit to having it all on one grand staff. The only reason to write it down is for someone to perform it, and putting it all one one grand staff makes it extremely difficult to perform it. If your ability to read and understand it is what you want, then the best approach is to practice reading multiple staves at once, like a conductor does.